# How to find all the collections from mongoose

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am supposed to find all the collections stored in the a mongo database.

```
require('../app/models/schemas'); //loading application schemas
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection error:'));
var collections = db.collections();
console.log(collections);
```

Here collections prints a combined `'json'` data of all the schemas.

But i want to find all the collections stored in the mongo test database.
How to achieve it with mongoose?

Comment: I posted an aswer before on a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961387/trying-to-get-a-list-of-collections-from-mongoose

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the collectionNames function to return a list of collections.

```
db.on('open', function(){
  mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function(error, names) {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } else {
      names.map(function(cname) {
        console.log(cname.name);
      });
    }
  });
});

=> database1.system.indexes
=> database1.users
=> database1.posts
```

Comment: This is no longer working. `collectionName` has been removed.
Look here for an updated answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30675970/2422544

Answer (score -4):

make sure mongodb is up and running, in the terminal:

$ mongo

> show dbs
>
> use [db_name]
>
> show collections

---

If you know in wich db your collections are :

$ mongo [db_name]

> show collections