# Trying to get a list of collections from mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to return a list of a dbs collections using mongoose. I'm following the directions set out here but http://grokbase.com/t/gg/mongoose-orm/122xxxr7qy/mongoose-get-a-list-of-all-collections. So here is my code

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    //if (mongoose.connection.readyState == 0){//checks if already connected to the database
    console.log("creating connection to the database");
    var Config = require('../configs/config');
    var config = new Config();
    config = config.getConfig().db.dev;

    if (mongoose.connection.readyState = 0 ) {
    mongoose.connect("mongodb://austin:password1@paulo.mongohq.com:10023/test1");
    console.log('mongoose readyState is ' + mongoose.connection.readyState);
    }
    var collection;

    mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
        console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
    });

    //trying to get collection names
    mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names); // [{ name: 'dbname.myCollection' }]
        module.exports.Collection = names;
    });
```

the only problem is that names returns as undefined. So is it even possible to return a list of collections using just vanilla mongoose?

Comment: Not directly familiar with Mongoose, but my general knowledge of Mongo and node leads me to believe your collectionNames call is returning undefined because you aren't actually connected yet.  If it's async, that method may fire before the 'open' returns.  Try placing that block inside of the open function.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try running your collection names function after connection.

```
mongoose.connection.on('open', function (ref) {
    console.log('Connected to mongo server.');
    //trying to get collection names
    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
        console.log(names); // [{ name: 'dbname.myCollection' }]
        module.exports.Collection = names;
    });
})
```

Comment: -1 because it does not work anymore, please update the answer, then I'll remove the downvote. For others, see Squivo's answer.

Comment: - 1 because, this is not valid answer as of today. Use `mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray((error, collections) => { //... })`

Comment: (This answer has been corrected since the comments by @zbr and @Vikram)

Answer (score 48):

Just came across this answer and though it may have worked at the time it appears `collectionNames` has been removed from the available function names in favour of `listCollections`

This other stack overflow post has a working example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29461274/4127352

Here is the link to the original docs:  http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.0/meta/changes-from-1.0/

Comment: In case it helps: I've tried to use `listCollectionsAsync()` after using bluebird's `Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.connection.db)` + package `asyncawait`, with no success (hangs when calling `listCollectionsAsync()` for no reason). However after a `console.log(mongoose.connection.db)` to check available methods I've found an undocumented `collections()` function (promisified as `collectionsAsync()`) which works perfectly O_o (mongoose 4.3.7)

Comment: Dangerous example, I copied code fast and didn't notice it drops collections in database. So please edit to contain actual code that lists collections
So careful!

Answer (score 6):

Here is how I managed to obtain all the names on the connected db.

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var collections = mongoose.connections[0].collections;
var names = [];

Object.keys(collections).forEach(function(k) {
    names.push(k);
});

console.log(names);
```

This solution works good on **mongoose 4.4.19**.

Comment: This DOES NOT lists collections in the connected database! It lists collections that were registered using the `mongoose.model` function. It lists collections even on an empty database, actually even prior to connecting to one.

Answer (score 2):

I tried all the previous answers and didn't receive a positive result. But I have got the array of collections with this code:

```
  let listOfCollections = Object.keys(mongoose.connection.collections);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are only working with Mongoose Models, that is all you need:

```
const connection = mongoose.connection;
Object.keys(connection.models).forEach((collection) => {
  // You can get the string name.
  console.info(collection);
  // Or you can do something else with the model.
  connection.models[collection].remove({});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to the top answer above, but this code displays the name for each collection, without the other added information (such as type, options, info, etc.).

```
const namesList = [];
mongoose.connection.on("open", function (ref) {
  console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
  //trying to get collection names
  mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function (err, names) {
    for (let i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
      // gets only the name and adds it to a list
      const nameOnly = names[i].name;
      namesList.push(nameOnly);
    }
    console.log(namesList);
    module.exports.Collection = namesList;
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 import mongoose from "mongoose";

 // code to create a connection..etc.

 const db = mongoose.connection.db;
 const collections = await db.listCollections().toArray();
 console.log(collections);
```

This works for me. Furthermore, you can loop through the output to get the desired output format.

**ps:** According to [MongoDb doc](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/listCollections/), we have certain fields like `nameOnly`, and `filter` to apply on the `listCollections` query. But that did not work for me with Mongoose. Please add in the comments if you get something.

Thanks!