# 'process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })' - Undefined is not a function (mongodb/mongoose)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I'm trying to connect to my **mongodb** using nodejs and socket.io. I am able to connect to the database because I get 'connection accepted' in my console but on the nodejs side, as soon as I - indeed - get

> Connection to mongodb://localhost:27017 established through mongoose

it immediately fails next with

> process.nextTick(function() { throw err; }) ^TypeError: undefined is
>   not a function at showCollections**

And here goes showCollections:

```
var showCollections = function(db, callback) { 
    mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function(error, names) {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } else {
        console.log("=>Listening mongo collections:");
      names.map(function(cname) {
        mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection(cname.name);
        console.log("--»"+cname.name);
      });
    }
  });

}
```

And here is the content of my database folder:

```
_tmp (empty folder)
local.0
local.ns
mongod.lock
```

I run the mongodb by typing **mongod --dbpath folder** and it successfully 'awaits connections on port 27017'.

Also, my node_modules from **package.json** (npm)

```
"dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.9.6",
    "socket.io": "latest",
    "mongodb": "~2.0",
    "mongoose": "*"
  }
```

Thank you very much for your help...

StackTrace:

```
> TypeError: undefined is not a function
>     at showCollections (/usr/share/nginx/www/index.js:77:25)
>     at NativeConnection.callback (/usr/share/nginx/www/index.js:46:3)
>     at NativeConnection.g (events.js:199:16)
>     at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:104:17)
>     at open (/usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:485:10)
>     at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (/usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:494:5)
>     at /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:453:10
>     at /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:59:5
>     at /usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:200:5
>     at connectHandler (/usr/share/nginx/www/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:272:7)
```

**EDIT:**

I'm as well having these problems when trying to run the nodejs instance:

```
{ [Error: Cannot find module '../build/Release/bson'] code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
js-bson: Failed to load c++ bson extension, using pure JS version
```

I tried fixing them as other questions here would tell but nothing worked either...

Comment: Can you post the actual stack trace that gets printed out? That should tell you *where* in `showCollections()` the error originates from.

Comment: @mscdex how can I print the stack trace? is it supposed to get printed by default?

Comment: Yes, it should have been shown under the TypeError that you got.

Comment: Which line is 75 in `showCollections()`?

Comment: @mscdex 77? 
    `mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function(error, names) {`

Comment: If your `db` parameter to `showCollections()` contains the database object to use, you might try using that instead of `mongoose.connection.db`. If that doesn't work, you might also post how you are connecting to mongodb and such.

Comment: The thing is this used to work, really... I just moved my files from a server to another and it stopped working, even after managing the dependencies and essentials... I'll try what you're saying and I'll let you know!

Comment: @mscdex if failed the same way ;( what do you mean `If that doesn't work, you might also post how you are connecting to mongodb and such.`? I can't think of any other things of relevance to put here...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

From the provided information, it looks like you are using mongodb 2.0 driver. The db.collectionNames method was dropped. Check out the "Db Object" section of this page - https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/0642f18fd85037522acf2e7560148a8bc5429a8a/docs/content/tutorials/changes-from-1.0.md#L38

They've replaced it with listCollections. You should get the same effect with:

```
mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray(function(err, names) {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
    else {
        names.forEach(function(e,i,a) {
            mongoose.connection.db.dropCollection(e.name);
            console.log("--->>", e.name);
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: In case it helps: I've tried to use `listCollectionsAsync()` after using bluebird's `Promise.promisifyAll(mongoose.connection.db)` + package `asyncawait`, with no success (hangs when calling `listCollectionsAsync()` for no reason). However after a `console.log(mongoose.connection.db)` to check available methods I've found an undocumented `collectionsAsync()` which works perfectly O_o (mongoose 4.3.7)

Answer (score 0):

For me this error started popping up when i had to force shut down my pc as it became unresponsive. Next time i started my express server this error popped up.  I solved it by running `npm install mongoose@4.0 --save` in the terminal.
May be this error pops up when your server or database is force closed and some code is not save in mongod behind the scenes.

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't you specify the full path and have an export module?
...something like:

```
mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function (err, names)
{
        console.log(names); // [{ name: 'dbname.myCollection' }]
        module.exports.Collection = names;
}
```

If I'm wrong it's because I don't fancy moongodb <strike>:)</strike>

Comment: I don't really think this is necessary, if I got your point... I don't think my problem lies there...

Comment: What's the outcome if you run db.getCollectionNames() ?

Comment: the same... so the problem might be getting the collection names, for whatever reason!