# When ever I use mongoose, i get an error that collectionNames function not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

After going through the native mongo commands I was trying my hand on the ODM which is mongoose which extends the functionality of MongoDB.

i started with a simple fetch my collection from an existing database on my localhost. I was able to get connected to my db but i could not get the collections. 
however i was not able to do so.

```js
 

 /**
 * Uses MongooseJS to Connect to MongoDB
 * .Maps out all collections within
 */

var mongoose = require('mongoose')
  , MONGO_DB = 'mongodb://localhost/astro';

mongoose.connect(MONGO_DB);

mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){
  mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames(function(error, collections) {
    if (error) {
      throw new Error(error);
    } else {
      collections.map(function(collection) {
        console.log('found collection %s', collection.name);
      });
    }
  });
});

mongoose.connection.on('error', function(error){
  throw new Error(error);
});
```

```
TypeError: mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames is not a function
at NativeConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/script.js:29:26)
at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:179:7)
at open (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:511:11)
at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:520:5)
at /Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:476:11
at /Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:60:5
at /Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:227:5
at connectHandler (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:286:7)
at g (events.js:273:16)
at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
at emit (events.js:182:7)
at /Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:504:23
at commandCallback (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:936:9)
at Callbacks.emit (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:116:3)
at null.messageHandler (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:282:23)
```

/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:289
      process.nextTick(function() { throw err; })
                                    ^

TypeError: mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames is not a function
    at NativeConnection. (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/script.js:29:26)
    at emitNone (events.js:80:13)
    at NativeConnection.emit (events.js:179:7)
    at open (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:511:11)
    at NativeConnection.Connection.onOpen (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:520:5)
    at /Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/connection.js:476:11
    at /Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongoose/lib/drivers/node-mongodb-native/connection.js:60:5
    at /Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:227:5
    at connectHandler (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:286:7)
    at g (events.js:273:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:90:13)
    at emit (events.js:182:7)
    at /Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:504:23
    at commandCallback (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:936:9)
    at Callbacks.emit (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:116:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/Users/sagarmunjal/Desktop/untitled folder/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:282:23)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...

Answer (score 3):

`mongoose.connection.db.collectionNames` has been deprecated. I'd suggest use `mongoose.connection.db.listCollections()` instead.

See another stackoverlow post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29461274/5214807)

Answer (score 1):

This seems to make sense, Moongose really doesn't have a collectionNames api.

Try something like:

```
mongoose.connection.on('open', function(){
        for (var i in mongoose.connection.collections) {
            console.log(mongoose.connection.collections[i]);
        }
});
```