# How to use mongoose collection in router file

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I am trying to add in autocomplete to a node/mongodb project of mine, and was trying to follow along with this tutorial (https://developer.mongodb.com/how-to/building-autocomplete-form-element-atlas-search-javascript/).

My API is 'roughly' set up like this:

```
index.js
// Importing routes
const searchRoute = require("./Routes/search");

// Connect to DB
mongoose.connect(
  process.env.DB_CONNECT,
  {
    dbName: "MyApp",
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useFindAndModify: false,
    useCreateIndex: true,
  }
);
app.use("/api/test", searchRoute);

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Sever is running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

```
Routes/search.js

router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    let result = await collection
      .aggregate([
        {
          $search: {
            autocomplete: {
              query: `${req.body.query}`,
              path: "name",
              fuzzy: {
                maxEdits: 2,
                prefixLength: 3,
              },
            },
          },
        },
      ])
      .toArray();
    res.send(result);
  } catch (e) {
    res.status(500).send({ message: e.message });
  }
});
```

I know this isn't working as the "collection" in my search route is not the actual db collection I need, and the tutorial adds in `collection = client.db("food").collection("recipes");` but I dont know how to pass this collection (or one like this) to routes file. I have tried using module.exports,  but it still says it is undefined. I saw this similar question ([Trying to get a list of collections from mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961387/trying-to-get-a-list-of-collections-from-mongoose)) but I could only get it to export information (such as collection names), and even if I specified the collection name, it still came up with an error of 'collection.aggregate is not a function'

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

...

router.get("/search", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const collection = mongoose.connection.collection('<your-collection-name>');

    let result = await collection
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much. What an annoyingly simple solution. Quick question, as I am pretty new to hobby programming, when I import something i.e mongoose, am I essentially getting that module along with all the changes I have made in other files, rather than a brand new copy of the module?

Comment: You're getting whatever is exported from that module. in this case mongoose keeps some internal "state" (e.g. connection, which you intialized by `mongoose.connect` in  your index.js module), and so it becomes available when you import it.