# Find Documents from Different Schemas

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently creating a web service which should manage different groups of people. I therefore created a Customer-Schema and every Document (different Schemas) in my MongoDB gets a field `customer`. Now if I want to delete a customer, I have to delete all documents that are related to said customer. My problem is, that I don't know how to do that without invoking all Schemas in a row with `Schema.remove({customer: customerId})`.
Is there a "global" remove/find command that searches every doc?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find all the collections from mongoose](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18537875/how-to-find-all-the-collections-from-mongoose)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the link provided by laggingreflex, I came up with a solution:

```
var modelNames = mongoose.connection.modelNames();
var counter = modelNames.length;
for (var i in modelNames){
  result.model(modelNames[i]).remove({customer: req.params.id}, function(err){
    if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
    counter--;
    if (!counter){
      result.remove(function(err) {
        if(err) { return handleError(res, err); }
          res.send(204);
      })
    }
  });
}
```

If someone has a better idea, I would love to see it. :-)

Comment: That might be better, if one rewrites the above code using the `async` package

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no.

This will have to be done collection by collection.

It is a general idea that removing documents in a database is a bad idea unless it's a queue, so It's generally a better idea to `mark` said user as inactive, rather than remove them and all of their documents.

Comment: Unfortunately a customer is a company with many users, so it is also a matter of storage, so marking inactive is not the solution I would prefer